# Irreducible polynomials $p(x),~q(x)\in \mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ such that $(x^3+1)p(x)+xq(x)=p(x)q(x).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Find all the irreducible polynomials $p(x),~q(x)$ of $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$
>   such that
>
> $$(x^3+1)p(x)+xq(x)=p(x)q(x).$$

**Attempt.** If we work with degrees, if $degp(x)=n$ and $degq(x)=m$, then $\max\{3+n,1+m\}=nm$ so $n(m-1)\geq 3$ and $m(n-1)\geq 1$ and
we get $n\geq 2$ and $m\geq 3$. But there seem to be a lot of choices, though. How can one proceed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Suppose that $p=q$. Then we can cancel and obtain $p(x)=q(x)=x^3+x+1$.

Answer (score 2):

In stead of $\max\{3+n,1+m\}=nm$ you should have $\max\{3+n,1+m\}=n+m$, as $\deg p(x)q(x)=n+m$, so either $n=1$ or $m=3$. This does not leave many cases. Do beware that if $m=n+2$ then the leading terms cancel, so that the degree is not $\max\{3+n,1+m\}$.

Alternatively, because $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are irreducible, rewriting the equality as
$$(x^3+1+q(x))p(x)=xq(x),$$
by unique factorization either $p(x)=q(x)$ or $p(x)=x$, from which the solutions are easily found.